# Adding Child items on same form as parent in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework-4.1

I am trying to create a simple quiz.
The database design is such that I can add any number of answers to each question.

I want to edit this all on the one form/page.

I would have fields for the question (text, date, islive etc), and then the option to start adding the answers.

The idea is to list out the current answers, with the ability to edit/remove and add new ones.

This is the bit that I'm not sure of the best approach.

I was thinking that I probably need to make ajax/jquery calls to ActionResults to achieve this, but not really sure? (I don't really mind if the page reloads, but I do want to keep the URL the same)

The above is just for the CMS side of things.

I have created an Entity-framework 4.1 DB Context, which I can query correctly (I can loop existing questions, then then loop that questions answers).

One idea I've had:
I have two forms on my page which post to different actions. I then just Redirect back to the initial view, and reload everything when adding the answers.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe best approach is that answers should be partial views?